# XNA how to make simulate animation from a single Update call

Tags: c#, animation, xna, draw

I want to capture a Flick touch event in Update method. In there, I increment the Figure in Y direction, for example 70. When drawing, the figure get drawn like jumping. How do I make it so it looks like doing animation? Note that I want to do this in a Flick event instead of multiple VerticalDrag events.

```
Update(GameTime...)
{
...
case GestureType.Flick:
    figure.rect.Y += 70;
...
}

Draw(...)
{
...
spriteBatch.Draw(..
...
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to smooth the movement over several calls to `Update`.

Comment: Ok, I think this is the only way... Thanks for quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer has been provided in the comment of the question by Cicada. Thanks!